# how to replace "OptimisticCache" in GraphQL flutter?

Tags: flutter, graphql-flutter

I just upgrade [graphql_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter/changelog) version "3.1.0" to "5.0.0-nullsafety.5".

IDE has an exception: "The method 'OptimisticCache' isn't defined for the type 'GraphQLService'."

My code:

```dart
    ValueNotifier(
     GraphQLClient(
      cache: OptimisticCache(dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
      link: link,
      defaultPolicies: DefaultPolicies(
        watchQuery: Policies(
          fetch: FetchPolicy.noCache,
        ),
        query: Policies(
          fetch: FetchPolicy.noCache,
        ),
        mutate: Policies(
          fetch: FetchPolicy.noCache,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  )
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to use a `GraphQLCache()`? It seems that you can specify through the  `GraphQLCache()` instance that you want to use an OptimisticCache.

See the documentation of graphql_flutter for GraphQLCache: https://pub.dev/documentation/graphql/latest/graphql/GraphQLCache-class.html

Answer (score -1):

```
final GraphQLCache cache = GraphQLCache(
  dataIdFromObject: uuidFromObject,
);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.